# Is there a DIN font family which has greek letters?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

If I want a DIN font style, I usually use either:

`DIN17SBOP-Regular`
or
`DIN17`

[image]

However neither of these have Greek characters. Is anyone aware of one?

Answer (score 1):

[Parachute Fonts' DIN](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/parachute/pf-din-text-pro/) supports Greek, and [FF DIN](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontfont/ff-din/) "partly supports Greek". The main difference you'll see is in the italics. PF DIN uses a true italic with a handwritten feel, FF DIN has a sloped roman oblique.

Comment: Thanks for this, I wasn't aware of these families. I was after something that looked a bit more like "classic DIN" these seem to be quite new iterations -- but they could do if I don't find anything else!

Answer (score 1):

Seemingly you have got a couple of usable suggestions in another answer. If it happens that you must use freeware you can try a trick. There's a free CAD program which contains a couple of fonts which resemble thin DIN style fonts. After installing the program the font appeared also in other Windows programs.

There's no real Bold nor Italic versions, they are available only in programs which create them mechanically by thickening and slating the regular version.

CAD program: DesignSpark Mechanical

Fonts: SpaceClaim ASME CB and SpaceClaim ISO CB

[image]

The glyph list shows this Greek and Coptic section:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll take a look into this. By the way, since you have such a high rep, do you know why my question has been downvoted?

Comment: Your question isn't a problem in color, layout, creation techniques nor design business., it can be seen as a request for a purchase recommendation. Many of us consider them less interesting or less valuable than things which they see to need trained skills or creative talent.

Comment: Eikös tuo saatappi olla ASME fontti ei DIN

Comment: Are the stack exchanges not English only?

Comment: @Q.P. OK. I removed my tribal language comment. But I have seen several texts written in other languages than English and even accepted, for ex. javascript, XML and others.

Comment: @user287001 it was a question rather than a demand -- I actually don't know the rules! I only asked because when I translated your comments into English -- I thought they were relevant and helpful for the post. I personally have no problem with people using other languages, it just tends to slow the information transfer as one must translate :)

Comment: Jut this was a full opposite of informative. The tribe has a tradition to talk non-informatively to foreigners (I am a foreigner) they do not like. Foreigner asks "how long it takes?" The answer: "It can take a few days, but it's possible that it takes more".